# How do I load a YAML styling file into HERE SDK Premium (Android)

Tags: android, yaml, here-api

I am currently developing an Android mapping application using HERE SDK Premium (I need the offline capability).

However when it comes to map styling, while using the SDK Lite makes it trivially easy (create the YAML file using the online style editor then load it into the app), the Premium SDK does not seem to have this feature (at least not in terms of the level of simplicity).

The [MapScene](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/api_reference/index.html) object available in the SDK Lite version (which facilitates this) does not appear to be available in the SDK Premium product.

Am I missing something? Is it actually possible to load a YAML styling file using HERE SDK Premium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lite SDK uses a different renderer than the Premium SDK, so at the moment the option to use a YAML style file is currently only supported in the Lite version.

Comment: Thank you. :) Hopefully they'll update the Premium version in the near future.

Comment: There's exciting stuff coming for our Mobile SDKs this year. Stay tuned!